# No puedo ver mi App publicada en Play Store

Tags: android-studio, google-play, google-developers-console

Hace unos días publique una App en play store...Pero, Tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

"La Aplicación no se muestra con el nombre que yo le di en el Google Developer Console" con el nombre **Oficialía de Partes Móvil**"

Pero al buscarla con el nombre del paquete **"mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes"** asi si me la encuentra

Que tengo que hacer para que la encuentre con el nombre que le doy desde Google play Developer Console?

anexo el manifest y build.gradle

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".PreferenciasActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".Drawer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_drawer"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".Modificar"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:parentActivityName=".Drawer"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Drawer" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".General"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:parentActivityName=".Drawer"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".Drawer"/></activity>

    <activity android:name=".Creditos"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:parentActivityName=".Drawer"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".Drawer"/></activity>

    <activity android:name=".Soporte"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:parentActivityName=".Drawer"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".Drawer"/></activity>
</application>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    //compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    //compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mínimo sdk soportado es 16 y tienes definidos permisos "comunes" que no hacen uso de hardware especifico:

```
Version 1.0 can access:
Photos/Media/Files
read the contents of your USB storage
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
Storage
read the contents of your USB storage
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
Other
view network connections
full network access
```

en este caso la búsqueda en google play se basa en la primera palabra, de hecho si buscas ["oficialía"](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=oficial%C3%ADa) no encuentras ningún dato , de hecho me parece que no es una palabra reconocida para google play.

**Te recomiendo agregues como keywords: "Oficialía", "Partes" y "Móvil".**

para esto agrega una descripción conteniendo esas palabras:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te sugiero leas la [**documentación**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=es)

> Utiliza las [prácticas recomendadas para la optimización de motores de
>   búsqueda (SEO)](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291) en la descripción de la aplicación, pero ten en cuenta
>   las políticas de contenidos de Google Play sobre infracciones
>   relacionadas con la dirección IP y con el uso de spam (por ejemplo,
>   prácticas fraudulentas con palabras clave, suplantación de identidad,
>   etc.).

Comment: Hola, @Jorgesys disculpa mi ignorancia, es la primera app que publico en play store.. Tengo una pregunta, Como y en donde Agrego las Keywords

Comment: Hace cuanto publicaste tu aplicación? deben estar las palabras en la descripción de la aplicación!

Comment: la app la publique hace 3 dias.. hace una hora modifique la descripcion,.. pero aún así nada.. pero si la busco con el nombre del paquete, así si me aparece